# Angular extending anchor element with directive on interpolated values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have angular on the front-end of an application with html characters being interpolated and rendered. The data is coming from a backend CMS.

Almost all of the anchor values are linking to the value of their inner text.

For example:

```
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">http://google.com</a>
```

Instead of repeatedly entering this same pattern I'd like to extend the a tag with a directive:

```
app.directive('a', function(){
return{
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        var value = $(element)[0].innerText;
        if(!attrs.href){
            attrs.href = value;
        }
        if(!attrs.target){
            attrs.target = '_blank';
        }
    }
  }
})
```

My data is coming into angular through bindings like this:

```
<div class="issue-article-abstact">
    <h6 class="main-section" realign>Abstract</h6>
    <p ng-bind-html="article.abstract | to_trusted"></p>
</div>
```

"article.abstract" would be a json object containing `<a>http://google.com</a>`

This currently only picks up anchor tags that are not rendered on the page through interpolation. Is it possible to create a directive that will see values on the page from bindings and extend their functionality through a directive like this?

Comment: not clear what elements aren't being affected and how they get into dom. Provide enough detail to reproduce problem. Also note not necessary to wrap `element` in `$()` ... it's already a jQuery or jQlite object

Comment: I've added some more detail, explaining how the data is being rendered on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular doesn't compile html that is inserted using `ng-bind-html`.

There are third party modules you can use to do it, however you could also do the conversion in a service, controller,  custom filter or httpInterceptor before data gets inserted.

Following uses jQuery since it seems you are including it in the page

Simple example:

```
function parseLinks(html) {
  // create container and append html
  var $div = $('<div>').append(html),
    $links = $div.find('a');
  // modify html  
  $links.not('[href]').attr('href', function(i, oldHref) {
    return $(this).text();
  });

  $links.not('[target]').attr('target', '_blank');
  // return innerHtml string
  return $div.html();
}

$http.get('/api/items').then(function(resp){
    var data = resp.data;
    data.forEach(function(item){
       item.abstract = parseLinks(item.abstract);
    });
    return data;
});
```

This will be more efficient than having to compile all of this html in the dom using directive also